# Pairs of numbers from two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,3,6,10,20] 
b = [2,4,9,12,15,22,24,25]
```

Now, I would like to make a new list, containing pairs from the two previous lists. The pairs are defined as such:

- The left value [l,..] : `a[i]`
- The right [..,r]: The highest number in `b` between  `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` if `a[i+1]` exists, else just greater than `a[i]`, if `a[i]`exists, else just greater than `a[-1]` with `0 < i < max(len(a),len(b))`

The result would look like that:

```
pair = [[1,2],[3,4],[6,9],[10,15],[20,25]]
```

Anyone knows how to do that ?

*This is what I have done so far:*

```
a = [1,3,6,10,20] 
b = [2,4,9,12,15,22,24,25]  

pairs = []
counter = 0
for i in range(max(len(a),len(b))):

try: 
    # get a[i]
    ai = a[i]
except: 
    ai = a[-1]

try: 
    # get a[i+1]
    ai1 = a[i+1]
except:
    ai1 = b[-1]+1

temp = []
for bi in b:

    if ai < bi and bi < ai1:
        temp.append(bi)

# Avoid adding the last element of b again and again until i = len(b)
if max(temp) == b[-1]:
    counter = counter +1

if counter <= 1:
    print(max(temp))
    pairs.append([ai,max(temp)])
```

It's okay, since it gets the job done, but I was wondering, if there is a better, more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: For starters, remove all those try/except blocks.  I assume you have those in there to handle the edge cases of array boundaries. But in practice, all that will do is hide real bugs in your code.

Comment: Are the lists sorted?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Yes, they are !

Comment: @selbie Yes. Do you know a way of how to better handle the edge cases ?

Comment: Start by writing your code without respect to edge cases.  Then identify the edge cases (end of list, empty list, element not found, etc...) and fix with conditional (`if` and `else`) statements.

Comment: can i assume both lists are sorted?

Comment: am I wrong or the clause `if a[i]exists, else just greater than a[-1]` is included in `if a[i+1] exists`. Moreover, what would you assign as a left value when `a[i]` doesn't exist? maybe 0 < i < min(len(a), len(b))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a binary search, since the arrays are sorted, you don't have to search for `a[i] < b[j]`, only for `a[i+1] > b[j]` (This code will return invalid results if there are no elements in `b` such that `a[i] < b < a[b+1]`):

```
import bisect

def pairs(a, b):
    for (a1, a2) in zip(a, a[1:]):
        yield a1, b[bisect.bisect_left(b, a2) - 1]

    yield a[-1], b[-1]

print(list(pairs([1,3,6,10,20], [2,4,9,12,15,22,24,25])))
```

---

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 9), (10, 15), (20, 25)]
```

Comment: This could be optimized a bit by passing the `lo` argument to `bisect_left` so it starts searching from the last place it found something

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
a = [1,3,6,10,20] 
b = [2,4,9,12,15,22,24,25]

merged = sorted(a + b, reverse=True)
mask = [(False, True)[x in a] for x in merged]


flag = True
good = []
for m, n in zip(mask, merged):
    if m is flag:
        continue
    else:
        good.append(n)
        flag = not flag

pairs = list(zip(good[1::2], good[::2]))[::-1]
pairs
>>> [(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 9), (10, 15), (20, 25)]
```